# Android animation looks jerky on device

Tags: android, animation, native

i am creating a simple animation in the android. Simply want to move some ImageView from 1 point to 2nd point on screen using following code.
img_animation is ImageView.

```
void StartAnimationOne()
    {
        m_StartAnimationId = 1;
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(20.0f, 400.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
        animation.setDuration(m_TotalAnimationTime);
        animation.setRepeatCount(0);
        animation.setRepeatMode(0);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //m_StartAnimationId = 2;
                //StartThreadOne();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        img_animation.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
        //matrix.postRotate((float) 180f, img_animation.getPivotX(), img_animation.getPivotY());
        matrix.postRotate(0f, img_animation.getDrawable().getBounds().width() / 2,
                img_animation.getDrawable().getBounds().height() / 2);
        img_animation.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

But when it run on the device , animation looks very jerky.
following warning coming on the logicat.

> I/Choreographer﹕Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

My `MainActivity` is

```
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class testinglayout extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

    ImageView img_animation;

    int m_TotalAnimationTime = 10000;
    int m_StartAnimationId = 1;
    Handler handler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testinglayout);

        GetReferences();
        //StartThreadOne();

        //new AnimationClass().execute();

        StartFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_testinglayout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void GetReferences()
    {
        img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glowbg);
    }

    void StartFirst()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //If there are stories, add them to the table
                StartAnimationOne();
            }
        });
    }
    void StartAnimationOne()
    {
        m_StartAnimationId = 1;
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(20.0f, 400.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
        animation.setDuration(m_TotalAnimationTime);
        animation.setRepeatCount(0);
        animation.setRepeatMode(0);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //m_StartAnimationId = 2;
                //StartThreadOne();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        img_animation.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
        //matrix.postRotate((float) 180f, img_animation.getPivotX(), img_animation.getPivotY());
        matrix.postRotate(0f, img_animation.getDrawable().getBounds().width() / 2,
                img_animation.getDrawable().getBounds().height() / 2);
        img_animation.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
    }


}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Generally the animation jerkiness will vary from device to device. I think you can help the smoothness by ensuring you're doing one animation at a time and your layout is as simple as possible around the view in which is getting animated. At least that's what helped me out

Comment: My layout has a bg image and a image to move on it. OnCreate i am just starting the animation.

Comment: on device you mean an emulator, or real device?

Comment: @jordi Castilla - i am testing on the device (real)

Comment: which model, api and how much free memory (ram and internal)?

Comment: *Motorola E device* does not say too much.... actually this is usually done by emulators due lack of memory, your device runs *happy* in dayly use? or it's slow sometimes? also... can you show your main activity methods?

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testinglayout);
        GetReferences();
        //StartThreadOne();
        //new AnimationClass().execute();
        StartFirst();
    }

Comment: Its a simple activity just on create i am starting the animation. i tried all option runOnUiThread , Thread thread = new Thread() , AsyncTask<String, String, String> all option. but not worked.

Comment: please, update your question, it's really hard to read code in comments

Comment: also, you don't call your animation in the `onCreate`, either we can't know which other methods do... please create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll be glad to take a look, but without all the info it's quite hard....

Comment: @Jordi Castilla - hi , i ve updated my question with my activity code . Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `device` instead of android simulator to `debug` and check the UI of application.
if You are thinking that application is working too much on main thread try to use `child threads` for some of long time taking functionalities, which also require lot of resource.
and choreographer skipped 37 frames means some of your animations not working properly try to update AVD and try the higher android phone to taste.

Comment: i am using device Motorola E. its not very big animation. moving image from 1 point to another.